# Loadrunner file upload and import error

Tags: performance, loadrunner

Here is file attachment and than import script I am getting the following error

```
 Action.c(128): Error -26488: Could not obtain information about submitted file "C:\Users\domix\Documents\VuGen\Scripts\Credit_Report\Aaron IMPORTER.htm": _stat32 rc=-1, errno=2 [No such file or directory]. Using an empty file      [MsgId: MERR-26488]

web_submit_data("Upload", 
"Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CustomerReports/Upload?ConsumerID=40", 
"Method=POST", 
"EncType=multipart/form-data", 
"RecContentType=application/json", 
"Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CustomerReports/Details/40", 
"Snapshot=t10.inf", 
"Mode=HTML", 
ITEMDATA, 
"Name=name", "Value=Aaron IMPORTER.htm", ENDITEM, 
"Name=chunk", "Value=0", ENDITEM, 
"Name=chunks", "Value=1", ENDITEM, 
"Name=file", "Value=Aaron IMPORTER.htm", "File=Yes", ENDITEM, 
LAST);
```

Please explain how to correct this error (This is where I am upload the file and importing it into system)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the forum post, LoadRunner captures any form based file uploads as `web_submit_data` with the file name (and location) within the list of data within the request. An example request:

```
 web_submit_data("FileUpload",
    "Action={URL}",
    "Method=POST",
    "EncType=multipart/form-data",
    "TargetFrame=",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Mode=HTML",
    ITEMDATA,
    "Name=File", "Value=C:\\testdata\\readme1.txt", "File=yes", ENDITEM,
    LAST);[enter link description here][1]
```